# Make React app listens to a standard change event from browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the chrome or firefox console, in a discogs artist page (e.g. https://www.discogs.com/artist/251950-Europe-2), I would like to trigger the React change event for the select#show element.

In chrome console Event Listeners, for the select#show element, you can see the ancestor "change" event on the "div#app" element.
It's this event that causes the new content to load when changing the select#show index.

In the chrome console, I change the selected index :

`document.getElementById('show').selectedIndex=0`

Then I trigger the div#app "change" event :

`document.getElementById('app').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`

But nothing happens. New content does not load.

How can I trigger the true React div#app change event ?

Comment: Using JavaScript to Trigger Native Events [link_1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) [link_2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Or if you want to do it manually:
Using React DevTools [link_1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) [link_2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/)

Comment: I found the trick : The event must be dispatched with the bubbles parameter : `document.getElementById('show').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})`